# Identifying the space in commas with regular expression

Tags: regex

I have a data separated by spaces, but one of the data has special format with commas.

For example:

```
A B C,D,E,F G H
```

The start of comma group is detected with "[^\s]+\,", and the end of the group is with "\,[^\s+]".
In this example, the comma group starts with "C," and ends with ",F". The number of commas is more than one. 
There is only one comma group, but the location can vary.

I can use `\s+` to separate 5 data groups ([A],[B],[C,D,E,F],[G],[H]), but the issue is that there can be spaces in the data in the data group that has comma in it.

For example:

```
A B C,D E F,G H I,J K L M
```

There is no spaces before and after comma.

In this case, We have 6 groups ([A], [B], [C,D E F,G H I,J], [K], [L], [M]).

How can I get this result with regular expression? I'm using Python and Scala.

Comment: Can you clarify why E to J are grouped with C in the 2nd example?

Comment: tell us what you want as output for second example?

Comment: Is it that there is one and only one data group that contains commas?

Comment: does the group with commas have to have 3 commas?

Comment: Which regex flavor or language are you using?

Comment: In `B C,D E F,G H I,J K`, what is the rule to tell us that you expect `B`, `C,D E F,G H I,J`, `K` as opposed to `B`, `C,D`, `E`, `F,G`, `H`, `I,J`, `K`? Is it because you expect exactly three commas?

Comment: @zx81 - As comma before J is the last one.

Comment: Ah, I had missed that there is only one comma group at the most. :)

Answer (score 3):

A definitive answer depends on your flavor, but here is a regex that will separately match the "comma" group and the non-comma group. The comma group goes into capturing match 1; and the non-comma groups go into capturing group 2

```
(\S+,.*,\S+)|(\S+)
```

Answer (score 0):

***Note:*** *this will only work with PCRE.*

```
\G[^,]+?\K\s+|(?:(?!.*,)\s)+
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/lZ9fS2)

---

The first group (before the commas) uses two PCRE-only shortcuts (`\G` and `\K`) to work around the fact that we can't do a variable-length lookbehind to make sure there are no commas before the match.  How this works is `\G` starts at the beginning of the string or the end of the last match, the we keep going as long as there are no commas, throw away everything matched with `\K`, and then match our whitespace.  As soon as we hit our first comma, this will no longer be able to match and we will fall into the second group.

The second group (after the commas) uses a repeating negative lookahead.  As long as there are no commas ahead of the expression, it matches a whitespace character.  In other words, this will only match whitespace after the last comma.  These two groups will leave any whitespace untouched from the comma group.

```
(?# BEFORE THE COMMA GROUP)
\G      (?# the beginning of the string OR end of last match)
[^,]+?  (?# lazily match non-comma characters)
\K      (?# throw away everything to the left)
\s+     (?# match 1+ whitespace)

|        (?# OR)

(?# AFTER THE COMMA GROUP)
(?:     (?# start non-capturing group for repetition)
  (?!   (?# start negative lookahead)
    .*, (?# look for a comma)
  )     (?# end negative lookahead)
  \s    (?# match whitespace)
)+      (?# repeat group 1+ times)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using : `([A-Z],(.*){2}?,[A-Z])|\s+`

You didn't specify a language, but here is a C# example that splits the string into groups per your question and desired output.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string t = "A B C,D E F,G H I,J K L M";
    Console.WriteLine(t);
    var r = Regex.Split(t, @"([A-Z],(.*){2}?,[A-Z])|\s+");
    foreach (string s in r)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            continue;
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The output looks as follows:

```
A B C,D E F,G H I,J K L M
A
B
C,D E F,G H I,J
K
L
M
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd use regex engine supporting infinite repetitions in lookbehind, then the following regex would be fine for **split** operation.

```
(?<!,.*)\s+|\s+(?!.*,)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

But since you use Python and Scala and they do not support infinite repetitions in lookbehind, then the following might work for you (select all matches).

```
\w,\w.*\w,\w|\w
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/kF5wW7)**

Answer (score 0):

Here are two versions of a simple solution that will work in Python. See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/aD1hB8).

```
[A-Z](?:,(?:.*,)?[A-Z])?
```

If needed, replace `[A-Z]` with something more complex (but still specific), for instance `\S` (see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/aO9iN5)):

```
\S(?:,(?:.*,)?\S)?
```

**How does it work?**

1. The `[A-Z]` or `\S` matches the first character of your token.
2. The optional non-capturing group `(?: ... )?` matches the rest of the token (the comma part), if present.
3. Within that group, `,(?:.*,)?[A-Z]`, we match the first comma, then the greedy but optional `(?:.*,)?` matches any characters up to the last comma (if there is another comma), then the `[A-Z]` or `\S` matches the character after the last comma.